# Mysql sort string as number

Tags: mysql, string, sorting

I have a field like this

```
    table A {text varchar(255) }
```

with entries like this

```
    text => A$123.34
    text => A$10.34
    text => $15.45
```

I want to sort those so they list as

```
    A$10.34
    $15.45
    A$123.34
```

I've tried many solutions posted here - cast to decimal, value * 1, value + 0, etc. but they all fail. I did find one that comes very close:

```
    select text as num from Table A order by substring(num,2) desc
```

This gives

```
    A$10.34
    A$123.34
    $15.45
```

I know it is because the substring is looking past two characters and the last entry only has one but I can't see how to fix that. Does anyone know how to get this to sort as I want?

In most of the posts I've seen it said to just store the value as a number. That is not possible due to the amount of changes it would require in the project.

Comment: `ORDER BY 0 + substring(num, 2)`

Comment: I would save the A$ (or any other type of prefix) in another column, then sort by this new column+amount and then concatenate both for output

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, as mentioned, that is not an option.

Comment: I tried adding the 0 + suggestion but it makes the list less sorted. I do appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
mysql> select * from A order by 0 + substring_index(text, '$', -1);
+----------+
| text     |
+----------+
| A$10.34  |
| $15.45   |
| A$123.34 |
+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you Bill. That mostly did it. There is one entry for $1,205.54 and that ends up either as the first result (ASC) or the last (DESC). Is there a simple fix for that? If not, it is fine as it is since I doubt there will be many entries over 999.

Comment: Maybe strip out the commas: `substring_index(replace(text, ',', ''), '$', -1)`